# Can I call function from previously loaded javascript on android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm loading javascript into a WebView from the Activity, the webpage being shown is external. The problem is that I'm not able to call a fucntion that I've previously loaded, neither access variables values. When I do `webView.loadUrl("""var a = 0; function foo(){a = 1;}""")` the code executes perfectly (this code is only an example). But if I then do `webView.loadUrl("""foo();""")` It gives an "foo not defined" error.
And yes, I'm loading the js after the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called setJavaScriptEnabled(true).

Also, have you tried loading the function like this

```
webView.loadUrl(
            """javascript:(function() {
            // my js code
            })()"""
)
```

Comment: I've javascript enabled and I tested it that way but still doesn't work. But thanks anyway.

Comment: What is the issue? Is there a console log error in Logcat?

Comment: The first time I load a couple of js fucntions they works as intended, but the second time I try to call one of those functions it does nothing. It seems like there is no persistance between the executions of js code. I've tried modifying a DOM element from the first js code and then checking it from a second `loadUrl` but I can´t see the change from there, its like it never happened.